# Parsing Script tag raw data into csv with python

Tags: python, json, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Basically i,m scraping data from a web that is availabe on their script tag but i,m unable to extract data into proper layout ,  there is my script tag raw data

```json
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "I Got Toddler Problems Tee",
    "url": "https://www.inspireuplift.com/I-Got-Toddler-Problems-Tee/iu/3136",
    "sku": "BMRSUQNGGS",
    "image": [
        "https://cdn.inspireuplift.com/uploads/images/seller_product_variant_images/i-got-toddler-problems-tee-3136/1629196991_Toddlerproblemsmauv.png",
        "https://cdn.inspireuplift.com/uploads/images/seller_product_variant_images/i-got-toddler-problems-tee-3136/1629196991_Toddlerproblemsltgray.png",
        "https://cdn.inspireuplift.com/uploads/images/seller_product_variant_images/i-got-toddler-problems-tee-3136/1629196991_Toddlerproblemsblk.png",
        "https://cdn.inspireuplift.com/uploads/images/seller_product_variant_images/i-got-toddler-problems-tee-3136/1629196991_Toddlerproblemspk.png",
    ],
    "description": "BMRSUQNGGS",
    "brand": {"@type": "Thing", "name": "InspireUplift"},
    "aggregateRating": {"@type": "AggregateRating", "ratingValue": 0, "reviewCount": 0},
    "offers": {
        "@type": "AggregateOffer",
        "highPrice": 32.97,
        "lowPrice": 29.97,
        "offerCount": 24,
        "priceCurrency": "USD",
        "offers": [
            {
                "@type": "Offer",
                "url": "https://www.inspireuplift.com/I-Got-Toddler-Problems-Tee/iu/3136?variant=37621",
                "priceCurrency": "USD",
                "sku": "BMRSUQNGGS-1",
                "alternateName": "I Got Toddler Problems Tee - Mauve/S",
                "price": 29.97,
                "priceValidUntil": "2022-01-10",
                "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock",
                "seller": {"@type": "Organization", "name": "InspireUplift"},
            },
            {
                "@type": "Offer",
                "url": "https://www.inspireuplift.com/I-Got-Toddler-Problems-Tee/iu/3136?variant=37622",
                "priceCurrency": "USD",
                "sku": "BMRSUQNGGS-2",
                "alternateName": "I Got Toddler Problems Tee - Mauve/M",
                "price": 29.97,
                "priceValidUntil": "2022-01-10",
                "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock",
                "seller": {"@type": "Organization", "name": "InspireUplift"},
            },
            {
                "@type": "Offer",
                "url": "https://www.inspireuplift.com/I-Got-Toddler-Problems-Tee/iu/3136?variant=37623",
                "priceCurrency": "USD",
                "sku": "BMRSUQNGGS-3",
                "alternateName": "I Got Toddler Problems Tee - Mauve/L",
                "price": 29.97,
                "priceValidUntil": "2022-01-10",
                "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock",
                "seller": {"@type": "Organization", "name": "InspireUplift"},
            },
        ],
        "shippingDetails": {
            "@type": "OfferShippingDetails",
            "shippingRate": {
                "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
                "value": "0",
                "currency": "USD",
            },
        },
    },
}
```

i want to extract all variant name , imag url , size , color by extracting variant url
i want to getting back like this way
[i want data in this layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPZT3.png)
any one please help me i,m learning python here is my code

```py
r = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
scripts = soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json').string
data = json.loads(scripts)
image = data["image"]
try:
    altname = data["offers"]["offers"]
except KeyError:
    print("not found")
for item in altname:
    area = item["alternateName"]
    detail = {"image": image, "name": area}
    print(detail)
    newlist.append(detail)
    print("saving")
df = pd.DataFrame(newlist)
df.to_csv("first_list.csv")
```

I'm getting back this, all images urls in one cell inspite infront of variant color
[i,m getting back this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPZT3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is provided based on one json file (one product). Both uploaded screenshots are the same. It is better to use `data.get('key')` instead of `data['key']`.

`[data.get("name")] + [""] * (len(offer) - 1)` to create same length columns, otherwise we get error when we create a data frame, because product name is inside the cells just the first time.

```py
r = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
scripts = soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json').string
# if below line did not work try with data = json.loads(scripts)
data = json.loads(json.dumps(scripts))
size, color, url = [], [], []

offer = data.get("offers").get("offers")

product_name = [data.get("name")] + [""] * (len(offer) - 1)
if offer:
    for item in offer:
        size_color_list = item["alternateName"].split(" - ")[1].split("/")
        url.append(item["url"])
        color.append(size_color_list[0])
        size.append(size_color_list[1])

detail = {
    "product_name": product_name,
    "variant_color_name": color,
    "variant_size": size,
    "variant_image": url,
}

try:
    df = pd.DataFrame(detail)
except Exception as e:
    raise e
else:
    df.index += 1
    # df.to_csv('first_list.csv')
    df.to_excel("first_list.xlsx")
```

Comment: data = json.loads(scripts) Works but i,m gettinng back variant url inspite of image urls

Comment: product_name variant_color_name variant_size variant_image
1 Good Taste In Dogs Tee Black Heather S https://www.inspireuplift.com/Good-Taste-In-Dogs-Tee/iu/2190?variant=24964
2  Black Heather M https://www.inspireuplift.com/Good-Taste-In-Dogs-Tee/iu/2190?variant=24965
3  Black Heather L https://www.inspireuplift.com/Good-Taste-In-Dogs-Tee/iu/2190?variant=24966
4  Black Heather XL https://www.inspireuplift.com/Good-Taste-In-Dogs-Tee/iu/2190?variant=24967
5  Black Heather 2XL https://www.inspireuplift.com/Good-Taste-In-Dogs-Tee/iu/2190?variant=24968

Comment: the main question is: **I'm getting back this, all images urls in one cell**, so I solved this for you!  
what do you exactly mean by variant url and image urls inside the json? did you know that the url changes based on size and color? did you change the screenshots? can you provide a manual excel (screenshot) in which the urls are complete? in the screenshot I just see a part of urls. Also, it is better to edit your post and put a complete json with two products.

Comment: yeah i understand so i will have to extract all variants url  to get their image urls

Comment: I guess yes. could you accept the answer if the problem is solved? Thank You :) @babarakhter

Comment: again extremly thankfull yes this is my answer ,, sorry  if may i want to know how to scrap from list of each url

Comment: you're welcome :). But I mean by accept is clicking on my answer here [image](https://ibb.co/vwbcCSW) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70646452/7106343) and make this answer accepted/green. _how to scrap from list of each url_, you should ask a separate question, it is not recommended to ask multiple questions in one post.

Comment: yes why not Thanks